# How to list all balances of tokens managed by an eosio.token contract?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos, eosio.token

Let's say I have deployed the standard eosio.token contract to an account called "myeosiotoken," and I have used it to create an "ABC" token. Then, I issue 1,000 ABC to "someaccount1" and 2,000 ABC to "someaccount2."

I can retrieve the balance of 1,000 ABC on someaccount1 with:

cleos get table myeosiotoken someaccount1 accounts

And I can retrieve the balance of 2,000 ABC on someaccount2 with:

cleos get table myeosiotoken someaccount2 accounts

Is there a way to use cleos to retrieve a list of ALL balances of token ABC in the accounts table?

Is there a way to use cleos to retrieve a list of ALL balances of ALL tokens in the accounts table?

Comment: Just use cleos get table myeosiotoken myeosiotoken accounts to retrieve balance.

Comment: Unfortunately, that will only retrieve the token balance held by the contract itself.

Comment: yes that you exactly asked in first question.

Comment: My bad, that's poor wording on my part. Fixing it.

Comment: no problem.....

Comment: Issue token to main account(contract account) and then transfer them to other accounts it will be a good way to obtain all balances by cleos otherwise you will not able to retrieve ALL balance. If you don't want to do that then modify eosio.token contract as per your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it with a standard eosio.token contract would be to use something like the `state_history_plugin` to see which accounts had the `open` command used on them, and then write a script to loop through all of those accounts with the `get table` command you state in the question.

If you are capable of adapting the contract for yourself, then you can always add another table which would list all of the users and their current balances.

You can also check all scopes with:
`cleos get scope -t accounts myeosiotoken`

Comment: I just found out about "cleos get scope -t accounts myeosiotoken", it lists all "scopes" (which seems to mean blockchain accounts, in my mind) that "have" records in the given table (in that case, "accounts"). If you omit the -t parameter, it lists all accounts that "have" (whatever that means in the memory model) any table records that "originate" (again, whatever) from the given contract/account (myeosiotoken in this case). It won't list the token balances, but it seems to give the full list of accounts that have a table row/balance that I can query.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that! I added it to the answer

Comment: unfortunately the newer version of cleos does not support the command any longer. `cleos get scope -t accounts myeosiotoken` throws the error: `ERROR: ExtrasError: [scope -t]`. Is there another way to get all scopes of a table using cleos?

Comment: It works for me on EOS v2.1, which version of EOS are you using?